# Como paso parametros de mi vista al modelo donde se encuentra el metodo el cual ocupa recibir el parametro?

Tags: php

Lo que pasa es que solo ocupo pasar un parametro desde mi vista hacia el modelo donde esta el metodo por ejemplo:

*VISTA:

```
<h1>    <?php foreach($this->modelo->Listar(2) as $r):?>
        <?php echo $r->contenido ;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
</h1>
```

"Listar" es el nombre de mi metodo que esta en el modelo

*MODELO:

```
public function Listar($id){
    try{


        $query = $this->v->prepare("SELECT * FROM parrafo WHERE id_parrafo=?");
        $query->execute(array($id));        
        return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    }catch(Exception $e){
die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Quiero pasar el parametro de la vista al modelo y se asigne en el sigo de "?"

Espero darme a entender es mi primer pregunta el este sitio.

Comment: En donde tienes el valor del id en la vista?

Comment: Gracias por responder, por ejemplo ahi acabo de editar le puse el numero "2"   para que por ejemplo quede la setencia where id_parrafo=2

Comment: Lo harias exactamente asi como lo tienes.  Te marca algun error?

Comment: Si me sale este Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: Cual es la linea 16?

Comment: Es la primera donde esta el foreach, como que no reconoce el parametro

Comment: Creo que necesitas agregar mas codigo.  El error es probablemente porque la variable `$this` no es un objeto.

Comment: como dice @alamfcm debes agregar mas codigo, pero tengo una pregunta, la variable [array($id)] de donde sale ?

Answer (score 0):

deben mandar el parametro a la sentencia preparada ejemplo.

```
public function Listar($id){
    try{


     $query = $this->v->prepare("SELECT * FROM parrafo WHERE id_parrafo=?");
     $sentencia->bindParam("s", $id);
     $query->execute($query);        

     return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

   }catch(Exception $e){
     die($e->getMessage());
   }
}
```